# Calculate Number of Times Weight Changes more than a percentage

Tags: r

Suppose we have a table  `A`  with   `date`  and  `weight`  columns. Basically, this is daily weight data across 10 years. We want to count the number of times the weight has changed more than 3% in either direction. Is the below pseudo-code slightly correct:

```
count = 0
for (i in 1:nrow(A))
  {
    weight_initial = weight[i]
    for (j in 1:nrow(A))
      {
        weight_compare = weight[j]
        if(weight_compare >= 1.03*weight_initial || weight_compare <= 0.97*weight_initial)
          {
            count ++
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not that sure I understand your question...
Can you add some sample data and the desired output, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to do vectorized computations in R whenever possible. This is a quick and dirty approach (does twice as many computations as necessary, but should still be pretty quick):

```
weight <- rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.1)
wtcomp <- outer(weight,weight,"/")   
sum(abs(wtcomp[lower.tri(wtcomp)])>0.03)
```

This solution is similar to what would be produced by your pseudocode, except that yours does comparisons between present and both past and future values - so yours would (I think) produce double my answer.

Do you really want to count weight gain/loss against *all* future times?  e.g. should weight = (1,2,2,2,2) really be counted as 4 weight-gain events and not just one?

Comment: Yes because the weights will have high precision and be different from each other. In any case, is my solution correct?

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear for me what is the output you want. So, if you have your time series of weights:

```
a <- c(1,1.5,2,4,3, 3.005, 3.05, 0.5, 0.99)
```

and you want to compare each measurement just against the initial measurement to check how many times it changed more than 3%:

```
sum(abs((a-a[1])/a[1]) > 0.03)
```

But if you want to calculate how many times there was a daily change higher than the 3% with respect to the previous measurement, then:

```
sum(abs(diff(a)/a[-length(a)]) > .003)
```

Cheers  F.